# Create a new line every 140 characters with Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm working on a twitter bot that will tweet out text periodically, and I'd like to have it go line by line. But the block of text I have isn't seperated in 140 characters and I was wondering if there is an easy way to do so in Sublime.

Basically, I want the text to be separated into a new line every 140 characters.

Comment: So, try `.{140}` --> `$0\n`

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the `wrap_width` in your user preferences.

1. Open `Preferences.sublime-settings - User` using either the command palette or the drop down menu `Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings`.
2. Add the following line of code to the file

   ```
   "wrap_width": 140
   ```

*Caveat*: if that is the only line in the file make sure it is surrounded by braces

```
{
"wrap_width": 140  
}
```

*Caveat*: If you place it at the end of the file and there is a preference preceding it, you'll need to add a comma to the end of the previous line

```
{  
...,  
some_other_preference,  
"wrap_width": 140  
}
```